# child web component isnt receiving data object

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I have a parent web component saying:

```
<my-datagrid data="{{subdata}}" columnHeaders="{{subheaders}}"></my-datagrid>
```

In the parent I do:

```
@property
List<Map> subdata;
@property
List<String> subheaders;
void attached(){
  clear("subdata");
  clear("subheaders");
  addAll("subdata", getData());
  addAll("subheaders", getHeaders());
}
```

It is pretty simple and straight forward.  `my-datagrid` though, seems to not receive the data put into `columnHeaders`

So in my Created function, I was saying:

```
@property
List<String> columnHeaders;
@property
List<Map> data;

DivElement _header;

void attached(){ 
  _header = $['headerRow'];

  setColumns();
  print(columnHeaders);    //this   these two items
  print(data);             //this         both return null still
  print("finsihed attached");

}

void setColumns(){
  if (columnHeaders == null){ print("columns is null"); return; }
  _header.children.clear();
  for(int i = 0; i < columnHeaders.length; i++){
    print(columnHeaders[i]);
    var col = new DivElement()
      ..setInnerHtml(columnHeaders[i]);
    _header.children.add(col);
  }
}
```

Since i define it in the on create.  I think it is creating the child elements first, and then creating the parents, so it creates subdata as null and pass those in.

I tried an alternate approach and set the functions getData/getHeaders to static functions and set them in the instantiating such as:

```
@property
List<Map> subdata = getData();
@property
List<String> subheaders = getHeaders();
```

but that didnt work either.  What am i missing which is preventing data from being passed into the child webcomponent?

Comment: At first I'd suggest to move all code that accesses the DOM from the `created` constructor to `attached` or `ready`. If it still doesn't work please add a comment and I'll have another look

Comment: PolymerElement has a Ready/Attached function?

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/registration-and-lifecycle#lifecycle-callbacks

Comment: Still not working.  Moved content of created to attached for parent and child.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the new code?

Comment: You need to use `set('propName', newValue)` to update property values. See also https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/properties#list-mutation-methods for how to update arrays (I haven't found the mention of `set()` but I'm sure it's there somewhere)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer When changing the main, it stills says null though?

Comment: I noticed they have a setall, but since this is just a base set, i figured doing a clear and add all does just as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `@Observable` to `@property` for the `my-datagrid` component, that should solve the issues.

Comment: I tried this, it didnt seem to accept the data on the ready state.